# how to render header footer to layout page in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I want to render header and footer in index.html, but I'm getting this error:

> ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '' in 'C:\Type_Script_WebStorm\BlastFromThePast\src\app' resolve '' in 'C:\Type_Script_WebStorm\BlastFromThePast\src\app'Parsed request is a module

my files are here :-
app.component.ts :-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: `
                 <app-header></app-header>
  `

})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

header.component.ts:-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',



templateUrl: './header.component.html'

})
export class HeaderComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

index.html :-

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>BlastFromThePast</title>
  <base href="/">



<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

</body>
</html>
```

app.module.ts :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';

@NgModule({



declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app component is not defined correctly:
if you want to have an html page you use

```
templateUrl: './app.component.html'
```

if you want to write the html in your component.ts you have to call it like this:

```
  template: `<app-header></app-header>`
```

with best regards

Comment: To solve the issue you just have to change in your app.component.ts the line templateUrl: ` into template: `

Comment: thank you guys im really a silly guy thanks now i try to implement it again thanks

Comment: Nailik please explain this also  suppose i have more than one index.html in angular2 application and and all index.html have <app-root></app-root> tag than how i can render diif-diif  content in diff-diif index.html in <app-root> because in real world application there will be more  .html files so how i can do this please explain this ??

Comment: It depends on your goal, a way would be to use the express library  to redirect your html that's how you can have multiple index but I don't think that's what you want. for a given index.html you can also have other selector than app-root. Another way would be to use the rooter library, like this, you can switch pages as you like(ex: login component -> homeComonent). you can find example in the following tutorial: [link](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5)

Comment: Nailik Superb explaination now i try to implement all way u described abose love u stackoverflow thanks Nailik

Comment: Nailik Another problem im facing that i want to fetech records from Mysql database and want to show on  index.html file how can we do this in Angular2.  can we use database with Angular2 please explain

Comment: For security reason, you can not connect database to Angular 2 directly as Angular 2 is a Client-side language.

You can build a RESTful service (API) that handles read/write requests with your database using a server-side language (nodeJS, java, ...)